# Creating a site with Drush doesn't work

Tags: 8, drush, installation

Trying to install Drupal 8 using drush.

```
drush dl drupal --drupal-project-rename=example
cd example
```

So far, so good.

However, when I get to this part:

```
drush site-install standard --db-url='mysql://root:my+Password@localhost/db_name' --site-name=Example
```

I've also tried:

```
drush site-install standard --db-url='mysql://root:my+Password@127.0.0.1/db_name' --site-name=Example
```

But I get the following error:

> Failed to connect to your database server. The server reports the following message: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user root@localhost (using
>       password: YES) Is the database server running? Does the database exist or does the database user have sufficient privileges to create the
>       database? Have you entered the correct database name? Have you entered the correct username and password? Have you entered the correct database hostname?

All of the answers are "Yes," so the install should work. Is it something wrong with my syntax? I have other Drupal sites on this server that I've installed manually, it's just the Drush install I can't get to work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one was tricky but I finally figured it out myself. The reason the installation was failing was because my MySQL password had special characters. Drush can't escape special characters, so I had to change the password using the following command:

```
mysqladmin -uroot -pOldPassword password newPassword
```

After that, it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

It is probably because you do not have a setting for the super user (user/1). You need to set the account user name and password, so you can login to Drupal.

```
drush site-install standard --account-name=admin --account-pass=12345 --db-url=mysql://dbusername:dbpass@localhost/db_name --site-name=Example
```

Comment: Tried your suggestion and got the same error. My MySQL password has a special character, + (plus sign). I think Drush isn't escaping it properly.

Comment: @GTSJoe maybe try it without the `--site-name=Example` part, else change your pass or create a new db user with a simple pass to test your theory.

Answer (score 0):

In your command you have not mentioned the mysql port. Please refer the following command.

```
drush si --db-url=mysql://db-user:db-pass@localhost:3306/db-name
```

Username and Password is optional, once the site is installed the auto-generated username and password will be provided on the console. Please note it carefully.